# Importing npm React Component imports the ES6 file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm attempting to import the following component: https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat.

Unfortunately, it's trying to import the `JSX` file instead of the compiled ES5 component, which causes the following error:

`Module parse failed: /Users/sean/development/platform/node_modules/rheostat/src/Slider.jsx Unexpected token (34:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

I was able to find a related issue in the repository [here](https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat/issues/98), but the answer is a little cryptic. I tried the same with a clean `create-react-app` setup and it worked perfectly.

Am I missing something here? As you can see in my webpack config, I'm only transpiling one folder and only two extensions, which means I'm expecting to import `ES5` components from `node_modules` and not anything that needs to be processed by babel.

### Package.json

```
"babel": {    
      "presets": [ "react", "es2015", "stage-0" ],
      "env": {
        "development": {
          "presets": ["react-hmre"]
        }
      }    
  }
```

### Webpack

```
module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname + "/../../react")
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
```

Comment: Try `import Rheostat from 'rheostat/lib';`

Answer (score 1):

This might help as working for me

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: ['babel-loader']  
  }
```